# Laravel Testing : Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\get()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-testing

I am going through a Laravel tutorial and stuck at a "Call to undefined function" error. So far I have 20 Tests with 28 Assertions and only this test fails. I can't find my typo. Tell me please what source code do I have to add additionaly. I am new to Laravel.

```
λ vendor\bin\phpunit --filter a_user_can_filter_threads_according_to_a_channel
PHPUnit 5.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 409 ms, Memory: 14.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Feature\ReadThreadsTest::a_user_can_filter_threads_according_to_a_channel
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\get()

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

There must be a typo, but I can't find it.

**ReadThreadsTest.php**

```
/** @test */
public function a_user_can_filter_threads_according_to_a_channel()
{
    $channel = create('App\Channel');
    $threadInChannel = create('App\Thread', ['channel_id' => $channel->id]);
    $threadNotInChannel = create('App\Thread');

    $this->get('/threads/' . $channel->slug)
        ->assertSee($threadInChannel->title)
        ->assertDontSee($threadNotInChannel->title);
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('threads/{channel}', 'ThreadsController@index');
```

**Channel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Channel extends Model
{
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function threads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Thread::class);
    }

}
```

**ThreadController.php**

```
public function index(Channel $channel)
{

    if ($channel->exists)
    {
        $threads = $channel->threads()->latest()-get();
    } else {
        $threads = Thread::latest()->get();
    }

    return view('threads.index', compact('threads'));
}
```

**Thread.php**

```
<?php


namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Thread extends Model
{

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function path()
    {
        return "/threads/{$this->channel->slug}/{$this->id}";
    }

    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
    }

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function channel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Channel::class);
    }

    public function addReply($reply)
    {
        $this->replies()->create($reply);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your full ReadThreadsTest class ?

Comment: `$this->get('/threads/' . $channel->slug)` isn't working; if you're trying to call a `GET` request on that URL, you'll have to use an HTTP client like `Guzzle`

Comment: I found my typo finally. This token ">" was missing: `->latest()-get()` Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found finaly my typo after few hours searching ...

this:

```
    $threads = $channel->threads()->latest()-get();
```

must be:

```
    $threads = $channel->threads()->latest()->get();
```

Now everything works.

Comment: If the solution is to correct typo, just delete the question.

Comment: I am getting this message: "Deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?" I didn't know if it was just a typo or this example from a tutorial didn't work with my laravel version. Laravel didn't show me an syntax-error or another error to help me locate this typo.